# How to write a regexp that matches from a character to end of line?

Tags: regex, qt

I want a regexp to clear (for each line) anything that comes after `#` sign. So I wrote the code like this:

```
contents.replace(QRegExp("#.*\n"),"")
```

However, since the `.` also matches the newline, this cleared everything after the first `#`. So how can I correctly write the regexp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a negated character class `[^\n]`

```
contents.replace(QRegExp("#[^\n]*"),"")
```

This will remove `#` and the rest of the line.

See the [regex demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uB5sN9/2) (it will work the same in Qt).

In case you need to also remove the newline after, add it to the pattern:

```
contents.replace(QRegExp("#[^\n]*\n"),"")
```

Comment: Thank you!! This worked!!. It took me a while to figure it out though.

Comment: *It took me a while to figure it out though*, Really? Which part of it is hard to understand? Actually that pattern is one of the easiest.

Comment: I didn't undertand, at first how the regexp "knew" when the line ended. Unitl it hit me that it is basically when you no longer have a "not a newline". I have a hard time with regexps in general. I know. Slow. Thank you.

Comment: @aarelovich: Please do not take  Shafizadeh's words to heart, he did not intend to be mean. We all learn new things about this or that every day.

Comment: ... or `QRegularExpression("#.*$", QRegularExpression::MultilineOption)`. In general, be very careful with the kind of line terminators you have.

Comment: @peppe: With `QRegularExpression`, a mere `QRegularExpression("#.*")` should be enough.